# TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable when using rdd.foreach()

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I'm trying to save files from S3 into hdfs, partitioned by year, month and day. 
I have the path of files in S3 along with date info in an RDD.

```
def saveFile(filePath): 
    df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .options(delimiter='|',header=True)
        .load(filePath[0],schema=schema)
    df.write.mode("overwrite") 
        .save(targetDir+"/year="+filePath[1]+"/month="+filePath[2]+"/day="+filePath[3])

filePathsRDD.foreach(saveFile)
```

The `RDD.foreach` function fails with the error:

> TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

Comment: Hi, have you tried wildcards ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639956/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-in-a-single-load

Comment: I want to save the files for each day in a separate folder, which is why I'm reading them by the day. I can also do this by reading it all in a dataframe (using wildcards) and saving it as parquet, partitioned by date. However, this operation requires high resultSize in the driver, a problem when we scale in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Collect first:

```
>>> for path in filePathsRDD.collect():
...     saveFile(path)
```

Comment: I'm aware I can do that. I'm trying to distribute it because I have a path for each day and years of data.

Comment: You cannot, sorry.