# Reading files from multiple sub folders in sparklyr

Tags: r, sparklyr

In Spark 2.0 I can combine several file paths into a single load (see e. g. [How to import multiple csv files in a single load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639956/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-in-a-single-load)).

How can I achieve this with sparklyr's spark-read-csv?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the usage of wildcards for filepath in sparklyr  is the same as SparkR so many folders can be combined into a single call.

Answer (score 1):

Code example to read several numbered CSV files in all sub folders of a specific folder on HDFS:

```
spark_read_csv(sc, path = "hdfs:///folder/subfolder_*/file[0-9].csv")
```

Note that depending on the size of the resulting object, you may want to set the parameter memory = FALSE.

Comment: Is it possible to define a numerical range for the subfolders. For example my subfolders are only 2 digit numbers each indicating a day of the month {01, 02 ,03 ... 31} ?

Comment: I believe this is possible using the regular expressions like the [0-9] part in the path string above. You can build, test and adjust a regular expression to your needs using sites like https://regexr.com/ and just use it in the path parameter of the code posted above.