# Read CSV files in parallel in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to pyspark and a little confused about how to use it.
I have a directory structure as following:

### Main Directory

- dir1 --> file1.csv, file2.csv, ...
- dir2 --> file1.csv, file2.csv, ...
- dir3 --> file1.csv, file2.csv, ...

I want to read and process these csv files with a parallel execution using SQLContext in pyspark. What I was trying to do was map directory names (dir1, dir2, ...) and call a worker function to process csv files inside that particular directory. But turns out I cannot have access to SQLContext inside the worker function to read csv file with a proper schema using pyspark.

Is there any solution to this problem? Or is there any other, more efficient approach I can take to do the same? I see that there are some questions answered about independent executions in pyspark like: 
[How to run independent transformations in parallel using PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048068/how-to-run-independent-transformations-in-parallel-using-pyspark)

But my problem is I want to read csv files using SQLContext inside each worker function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How many files dir1, dir2 and dir3 have? Are they equal?

Comment: @Prazy No, it can vary from directory by directory.

Comment: Can you follow the solution from eiTan LaVi: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639956/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-in-a-single-load

Comment: What version of spark you are using?