# How can I append JSON data to an existing JSON file stored in Azure blob storage through python?

Tags: python, json, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-python-sdk

I've been looking around the web to append data to an existing JSON file in azure storage, I also check on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66576663/can-we-append-data-to-an-existing-csv-file-stored-in-azure-blob-storage-through) post, but it didn't help. I have millions of JSON records coming in real-time which are available in python list and I want to append those JSON records to an existing JSON file in azure blob. Though my main data source is KafkaConsumer, and I'm consuming data from Kafka topic and I want that data into azure storage as JSON format. As, I'm using python and I don't want to read/write on my local hard disk, I just want like if I have list of JSON records I can directly append to JSON file which already in azure container.
Can anyone help me out or give some references, it will be pleasure for me. Thanks

Comment: Are you using the append blobs?

Comment: In start I only upload JSON file using upload_blob function and then I tried [append_block](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-storage-blob/12.0.0/azure.storage.blob.html#azure.storage.blob.BlobClient.append_block) function on this JSON file, but it gives authentication error as this . "ErrorCode:AuthenticationFailed
Error:None
AuthenticationErrorDetail:The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'hW87ugUtVXulSjA4ZpI6jc6vLU+tjj4KKM7/uWE2J6w=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT 1043
application/octet-stream"

Comment: How you doing the  authentication for azure storage?

Comment: I'm doing authentication when I create conection and it didn't give any issue when I create connection. I only create BlobServiceClient connection using account _url and account key after this I'm not doing any authentication but when I append to blob it gives authentication issue.

Comment: can you please edit question with code you tried ?

Comment: `blob_client.append_block(json_record, sys.getsizeof(json_record))` This is what I am trying to append into the existing blob.

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried in my system able to append the data to existing file, I taken the dummy json data for testing purpose you can pass the your json data

```
from azure.storage.blob import AppendBlobService
import json

def append_data_to_blob(data):
  service = AppendBlobService(account_name="appendblobex", 
            account_key="key")
  data1 = {}
  data1['hi'] = 'hello'
  json_data = json.dumps(data1)
  data = json.dumps(data1)
  print(data1)
  try:
    service.append_blob_from_text(container_name="test", blob_name="test1", text = data)
  except:
     #To create the blob and append data
    #service.create_blob(container_name="test", blob_name="test1")
    service.append_blob_from_text(container_name="test", blob_name="test1", text = data)
  print('Data Appended to Blob Successfully.')


append_data_to_blob("data")
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Data appended in the azure storage file after download open the file and view the data

[image]

Comment: I'm not able to import AppendBlobService, it is showing Module not found.

Comment: try with pip install `azure-storage --upgrade` and again try with import statement

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Comment: Okay thanks @ShrutiJoshi-MT for your cooperation, definitely it was very helpful for me.

Comment: @ShrutiJoshi-MT can we access this appendblob from databricks. As per the MS documention, we cannot read the append blobs in databricks.